Apollo GraphQL: Convert Json String into Response Object
I am using the Java 17 library to make queries to a GraphQL endpoint. Everything works OK However, I want to convert a JSON string into a Response Object. How can this be done? I am trying to access this library in Java from Kotlin. However, could not get Operation.parseJsonResponse working . Does anyone know how to use this in Java?
com.apollographql.apollo.api.Response;

Kotlin resource: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/kotlin/advanced/no-runtime#converting-querydata-back-to-json
val response = operation.parseJsonResponse(jsonReader)

Resource: How does one manually convert Apollo Android-generated objects into JSON strings and back?

"However, could not get Operation.parseJsonResponse working". What is happening? Are you getting an error? Are you getting unexpected results? Please explain the problem you're having.
